# "Package EntityFramework 5.0.0 was restored" after mistype in Add new item

Tags: c#, visual-studio, package

When I was adding new item to sollution (Shift+alt+c), by accident I added nonsense suffix, something like `xx.tt`. Security warning popup showed, I pressed cancel to stop process. Removed item immediately, but VS gives me following warning: `Package 'EntityFramework 5.0.0' was restored using '.NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.6.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.1, .NETFramework,Version=v4.7.2, .NETFramework,Version=v4.8' instead of the project target framework 'net5.0-windows7.0'. This package may not be fully compatible with your project.`

Is it something i should worry about? I don't have that much code yet, I can copy-paste my way out of this if necessary... (no backup yet unfortunately).

Sorry about very rookie question, but I'm making my first app ever (WPF). I'm learning too many things simultaneously already. I just don't want to deal with this right now. But I don't want my sollution to become corrupted too.

Comment: That is the compatibility issue of the .net framework. Only backward compatible. If you want to call the higher version from the lower version, an error will be reported.

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Comment: Ehm, kinda... I started new project and copied all classes from corrupted old project into new one. And warning dissappeared, so one less thing to worry about. Still no idea what happened though.